# How do I use UTF-8 entities in a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

Rails appears to be converting the ampersand at the beginning of the utf-8 entity to an HTML entity: `&amp;`

So `&#x25B2;` becomes `&amp;#x25B2;` but I would like to display a downward arrow instead, which is what the utf-8 entity would normally be.

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Here is what the view looks like:

```
<%= get_arrow_from_helper(order) %>
```

And here is what the helper looks like:

```
def get_arrow_from_helper(order)
    arrow = order == "ASC" ? "&#x25B2;" : "&#x25BC;"
    html = "<div>#{arrow}</div>"
    return html
end
```

Comment: Why not use the character directly instead of resorting to entities? Are your sites not UTF-8 themselves?

Comment: yeah you're right, that's what i should have done.  just like this: ▲

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Rails version are you using? If you are using Rails 3 (or `rails_xss` plugin), Rails will escape the content by default to prevent XSS injection.

```
<%= "Copyright &copy; 2010" %>
```

will print out

```
Copyright &amp;copy; 2010
```

There are several ways:

1. use the `raw` helper, but only if you are sure the content you are printing comes from a safe source.

   ```
   <%= raw "Copyright &copy; 2010" %>
   ```
2. mark the string as safe, but only if you are sure the string is really safe

   ```
   <%= "Copyright &copy; 2010".html_safe %>
   ```

Comment: This did work, but for whatever reason, my document is not interpreting the utf-8 correctly.  Not sure why.  But these methods did help to stop Rails from converting the ampersand.

Comment: Oops!  I was using decimal entities instead of hexidecimal.  I've updated the question so it's correct now.  The solutions offered by Simone work great.  Thanks Simone!  More on entities: http://santagata.us/characters/CharacterEntities.html